# What is the closest way to pass string arguments from bash script to matlab file?

Tags: bash, matlab, parameters

I have matlab file matlab_param.m

```
function matlab_param(param1, param2)

disp(sprintf('param1 : %s', param1));
disp(sprintf('param2 : %s', param2));
```

And I want to have bash script bash_param.sh that look like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
echo $2
./matlab_param.m $1 $2
```

I want to run this bashscirpt

```
./bash_param.sh hello world
```

and it will print

```
hello
world
param1 : hello
param2 : world
```

I googled for hours and couldn't find any exact solution for this. The closest one the I got so far is

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "try, run ('./test_param.m'); end; quit"
```

which I need to hardcode all parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
echo $2
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "try, test_param('$1','$2'); end; quit"
```

Comment: Sorry that I didn't explain it clearly. Now I add more explanation. If I try the way you suggest, it won't print those $1 and $2

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to pass arguments to matlab function I'd recommend to create a simple shell script:

```
matlab -nodisplay -r "try, test_param('$1','$2'); end; exit"
```

Then you can run in unix:

```
$ sh test_param.sh hello world
```

Not sure although how to avoid the MATLAB header output and if it will be passed to pipe.